# Compute cartesian product of elements in 1 array

Tags: javascript, arrays, cartesian-product

I want to compute the cartesian product inside the single elements of an array. There should only be 2 values at a time.
So if this my array is:

```
[["cat dog mouse"], ["blue red green"]]
```

The expected value is:

- cat, dog
- cat, mouse
- dog, mouse
- blue, red
- blue, green
- red, green

This is my buggy approach:

```
var arr = [["cat dog mouse"], ["blue red green"], ["apple orange banana"]];

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
        if(j >= arr[i].length){
            console.log(arr[i][j].split( " ")  + " "  + arr[i][0])
        }else{
            console.log(arr[i][j].split( " ")  + " "  + arr[i][j+1])
        }
    }
}
```

It gives me

- cat,dog,mouse undefined
- blue,red,green undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using **[`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** and **[`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)** loop

```js
var arr = [
  ["cat dog mouse"],
  ["blue red green"],
  ["apple orange banana"]
];

// iterate the array
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  // split the string 
  var inArr = arr[i][0].split(' ');
  // iterate the splitted string  array
  for (j = 0; j < inArr.length - 1; j++) {
    // iterate string next to current string
    for (k = j + 1; k < inArr.length; k++)
      // generate the output
      console.log(inArr[j] + ', ' + inArr[k]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close, some modified code

```
var arr = [["cat dog mouse"], ["blue red green"], ["apple orange banana"]];

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var items = arr[i][0].split(" ")
    for (j = 0; j < items.length - 1; j++) {
        for (k = j+1; k < items.length; k++) {
            console.log(items[j], items[k])
        }
    }
}
```

result:

```
cat dog
cat mouse
dog mouse
blue red
blue green
red green
apple orange
apple banana
orange banana
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[["cat dog mouse"], ["blue red green"]].forEach(function (item) {
    item.forEach(function (value) {
         var arr = value.split(' ');
         var hash = {};
         arr.forEach(function (firstItem) {
              arr.forEach(function (secondItem) {
                  if (firstItem !== secondItem && !hash[firstItem + secondItem] && !hash[secondItem + firstItem]) {
                      console.log(firstItem + ', ' + secondItem);
                      hash[firstItem+secondItem] = true;
                  }
              });
         })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution splited in partial solutions, one for the arrays and one for the combination without repeat.

```js
function combine(array, length) {
    function c(l, r) {
        var ll = l.slice();
            if (r.length === length) {
            result.push(r);
            return;
        }
        while (ll.length) {
            c(ll, r.concat(ll.shift()));
        }
    }
    var result = [];
    c(array, []);
    return result;
}

function get(array) {
    return array.map(function (a) {
        return combine(a[0].split(' '), 2);
    });
}

var result = get([["cat dog mouse"], ["blue red green"], ["apple orange banana"]]);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in **functional way**, just using **.map()** and **.forEach()** method :

```
var arr = [["cat dog mouse"], ["blue red green"], ["apple orange banana"]];


function print(item){
  //If there is one last item we stop the process
  if (item.length <= 1) return;
  else {
    //Retrieve head of our stack and shift the first item
    const head = item.shift();
    item.forEach((elm) => console.log(head + ',' + elm));
    // call our recursive function with the new array
    return print(item);
  }
}

function combine(arr){
  //Return array splited by using .map and .split operations, then iterate by using forEach and call our
  // recursive function
  arr
    .map((array) => array[0].split(' '))
    .forEach((value) => print(value));
}

combine(arr);
```

You can check the **[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CQLJIz7ELmkTHW8FQYsS?p=preview)**